# Geopandas with log-scale colormap

Tags: python, geopandas

If I have the plot below, how can I turn the colormap/legend into a log-scale?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GeoPandas plots are using matplotlib, so you can use normalization of colormap provided by it. Note than I am also specifying min and max values as mins and maxs of the column I am plotting.

```py
world.plot(column='pop_est', legend=True, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=world.pop_est.min(), vmax=world.pop_est.max()), )
```

[image: map]

Comment: Thank you, looks great! However, I get `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'colors'`. In the beginning of my script I have `import matplotlib.colors as colors`.

Comment: Got it, I have to remove the `matplotlib` :)

Comment: Is there anything for the `explore` method?

Comment: @Vovin no, you will need to do it manually.

Comment: @martinfleis I have solved this via a custom colourmap.

Comment: @martinfleis Wow thats great !! Helped me a lot !! By the way, what if I want to use this solution (log scale) bu want to keep non log labels ??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plot the log of the value instead of the value itself.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import log10

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
world['logval'] = log10(world['pop_est'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
world.plot(column='logval', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

Comment: If you do this, then your legend is not showing actual values you want to show.